# How to initialize 3 variables at once using when expression in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm able to initialize 2 variables of different types like that:

```
val (p1, p2) = when (someEnum: SomeEnum) {
    SomeEnum.x -> "NameX" to 100
    SomeEnum.y -> "NameY" to 200
}
```

How would I do the same but for 3 variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to` creates a tuple of 2 elements - `Pair<A, B>` so using a tuple of three elements `Triple<A, B, C>` is the solution.

```
val (p1, p2, p3) = when (enum: SomeEnum) {
    SomeEnum.x -> Triple("NameX", 100, true)
    SomeEnum.y -> Triple("NameY", 200, false)
}
```

For the variables of the same type:

```
val (p1, p2, p3) = when (enum: SomeEnum) {
    SomeEnum.x -> listOf<String>("NameX", "100", "true")
    SomeEnum.y -> listOf<String>("NameY", "200", "false")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Triple` is indeed a correct answer, but do consider a named data class instead. The [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) says the following:

> The standard library provides Pair and Triple. In most cases, though,
> named data classes are a better design choice, because they make the
> code more readable by providing meaningful names for properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Triple is the option of your question**

Kotlin language provides a simple datatype to store three values in a single instance. This can be done using a data class known as Triple. It is a simple generic class that stores any three values, there is no valuable meaning of the relationship between the three values. The comparison between two Triple objects is done on the basis of values, i.e. two Triples are equal only if all three component are equal.

**Class Definition –**

```
data class Pair<out A, out B, out C> : Serializable
```

There are three parameters:
A – type of the first value
B – type of the second value
C – type of the third value

**Constructor –**
In Kotlin, constructor is a special member function that is invoked when an object of the class is created primarily to initialize variables or properties. To create a new instance of the Triple we use:

```
Pair(first: A, second: B, third: C)
```

Kotlin example of creating triple using the constructor –

```
fun main() { 
    val (x, y, z) = Triple(1, "Person", 2.0) 
    println(x) 
    println(y) 
    println(z) 
}
```

**Output:**

1
Person
2.0